# Counting consecutive characters in a string

Tags: python, string, count, character

I need to write a code that slices the string (which is an input), append it to a list, count the number of each letter - and if it is identical to the letter before it, don't put it in the list, but rather increase the appearance number of that letter in the one before..
Well this is how it should look like :

```
assassin [['a', 1], ['s', 2], ['a', 1], ['s', 2]], ['i', 1], ['n', 1]
```

the word assassin is just an example of the need..
My code so far goes like this:

```
userin = raw_input("Please enter a string :")
inputlist = []
inputlist.append(userin)
biglist = []
i=0
count = {}
while i<(len(userin)):
    slicer = inputlist[0][i]
    for s in userin:
        if count.has_key(s):
            count[s] += 1
        else:
            count[s] = 1
    biglist.append([slicer,s])
    i = i+1
print biglist
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`Collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), dictionary is a better way to store this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> strs="assassin"
>>> Counter(strs)
Counter({'s': 4, 'a': 2, 'i': 1, 'n': 1})
```

or using [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> [[k, len(list(g))] for k, g in groupby(strs)]
[['a', 1], ['s', 2], ['a', 1], ['s', 2], ['i', 1], ['n', 1]]
```

Comment: This doesn't preserve the order of the letters.

Comment: @SilentGhost: Because that's what the question was. The answer doesn't match the example given by the question asker.

Comment: @SilentGhost "Well this is how it should look like :

assassin [['a', 1], ['s', 2], ['a', 1], ['s', 2]], ['i', 1], ['n', 1]"

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- the `groupby` solution is nice.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i am quite the starter.. i can't seem to make alot of sense from your help..

Comment: @Spectalecy have a look my [other solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13211561/846892).

Answer (score 2):

```
last = ''
results = []
word = 'assassin'
for letter in word:
if letter == last:
    results[-1] = (letter, results[-1][1] +1)
else:
    results.append((letter, 1))
    last = letter

print result # [('a', 1), ('s', 2), ('a', 1), ('s', 2), ('i', 1), ('n', 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only builtins:

```
def cnt(s):
    current = [s[0],1]
    out = [current]
    for c in s[1:]:
        if c == current[0]:
            current[1] += 1
        else:
            current = [c, 1]
            out.append(current)
    return out

print cnt('assassin')
```