# count letter and show in list

Tags: python, string, list

I need to receive a string from the user, present it in list so each organ in the list contains [the letter, the number it repeat in a row].

I thought my code is good but it doesn't work.
I used http://pythontutor.com and I saw that one the problem is that my var.next and current stay with the same value all the time.

somone have an idea?

Here is my code:

```
    string = raw_input("Enter a string:")
    i=0
    my_list=[]
    current=string[i]
    next=string[i+1]
    counter=1
    j=0
    while i<range(len(string)) and next<=range(len(string)):

        if i==len(string)-1:
            break
        j+=1
        i+=1
        if current==next:
            counter+=1

        else:
            print my_list.append([string[i],counter])
            counter=1
```

output:

```
Enter a string: baaaaab
As list: [['b', 1], ['a', 5], ['b', 1]]
```

Comment: Note that there is a [module named `string`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html). You should not use that name for variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) here:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [[k, len(list(g))] for k, g in groupby("baaaaab")]
[['b', 1], ['a', 5], ['b', 1]]
```

Or without using libraries:

```
strs = raw_input("Enter a string:")
lis = []
for x in strs:
   if len(lis) != 0:
      if lis[-1][0] == x:
         lis[-1][1] += 1
      else:
         lis.append([x, 1])
   else:
       lis.append([x, 1])         
print lis
```

**output:**

```
Enter a string:aaabbbcccdef
[['a', 3], ['b', 3], ['c', 3], ['d', 1], ['e', 1], ['f', 1]]
```

Comment: we didn't learn it yet.. we just in the seconed lesson.
I prefer to use something we learnt

Comment: @user1562379 added a simple solution as well.

Comment: wow! tnx so much @Ashwini Chaudhary, I try to solve it few days already.

Comment: @user1562379: You can make this simple solution even simpler - see my answer

Comment: can you just explain me this?
`code`
if len(lis)!=0:
      if lis[-1][0]==x:
         lis[-1][1]+=1
`code`

Comment: @user1562379 if the list is not empty then two conditions are possible: **1**. either the last element is same as the current character, if that is so then just increment it's counter by 1 . **2**. if the previous element was different then add a new sublist with the current character in it and a counter of 1.

Comment: i dont get it..
we need to check the string not lis. lis is only for add sublist to it.

Comment: @user1562379 we need to comapare both the current item from the string and the last item of the list.

Comment: if i want to rewrite the original input, can I do this?
`code`
my_list=[['a', 2]][['b', 2]]
print my_list[i][0]*my_list[i][1]
`code`

@Ashwini Chaudhary

Comment: why are you using `range(len(string))`, you can directly traverse over the string as I did.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19024/discussion-between-user1562379-and-ashwini-chaudhary)

Answer (score 1):

Simpler variant of Aswini's code:

```
string = raw_input("Enter a string:")
lis = []
for c in string:
    if len(lis) != 0 and lis[-1][0] == c:
        lis[-1][1] += 1
    else:
        lis.append([c, 1]) 

print lis
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easily using defaultdict:

```
import collections

defaultdict=collections.defaultdict
count=defaultdict(int)
string="hello world"
for x in string:
    count[x]+=1
```

To show it in a list you can do:

```
count.items()
```

which in this case would return:

```
[(' ', 1), ('e', 1), ('d', 1), ('h', 1), ('l', 3), ('o', 2), ('r', 1), ('w', 1)]
```

Comment: No you can't, as a dictionary will store an item only once.(See the first `o` is missing from your output)