# Python split by letter occurances

Tags: python, string, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [count letter and show in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211533/count-letter-and-show-in-list)

I am new to python.
I want to create a list by splitting a string into the amount of unique occurances of the letters in a string.
for a example:
google will be splitted into
g
oo
g
l
e

whats the best way? thanks!

Comment: Someone in your class was faster than you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211533/count-letter-and-show-in-list

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> strs="google"
>>> " ".join("".join(g) for k,g in groupby(strs))
'g oo g l e'
```