# Count consecutive non-binary and non-single character strings

Tags: python

I need to take a list in a .txt file, such as this one:
`bananaapplebananabananabananaappleapplebanana`
with no commas or white space in-between them, and output **the largest number of times** specific strings, specified by me, appear **consecutively**. So for example, in the example above, it would be:

```
banana: 3, apple: 2
```

I've looked at a few options, such as this one: 
[Counting consecutive characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197668/counting-consecutive-characters-in-a-string?rq=1)
But most options that I find either count consecutive *binary numbers* or consecutive *single characters*, but not full words. Other examples assume that the words are somehow separated, such as in a list with a new line for each word. I've tried `max(len)` but that doesn't really work here since what I'm counting are objects.

I realize that what I need to do is to use some kind of counter that iterates over the one-line list and counts the consecutive occurrence of each word, that I have somehow specified in my code, and overwrites the highest number of consecutive occurrences when it encounters a new, higher count of consecutive occurrences of that same word.

Any examples of how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Perhaps this may help. I would use the regular expression library. Then as a naive start you could iterate through your list of words you create and apply the re.finditer() function.

So something like this:

```
import re
long_string = "applesapplesbananasapples"
word = r'apples'
res = [(mtch.start(0), mtch.end(0)) for mtch in re.finditer(word, long_string)]
```

That would give you a list of tuples like so:
`[(0, 6), (6, 12), (19, 25)]`

Then you can iterate over that list and compare the final and first value of adjacent tuples. If they match then you have consecutive words, if not then they aren't consecutive and you end the counting there.

I have not coded the second part as that should be trivial but hope the first part helps. If not and you need a more comprehensive solution let me know.

Comment: How would I do this if the strings to look for are in a CSV file (and it would pull the strings from the first row of the CSV) and the program would then pull a specified .txt to compare against it?

Comment: In a csv file they would have a delimiter. So the best approach would be to use the csv module in the standard library. You can then use the .sniff() method to get the dialect and from there you can get the delimiter. Then I would just 'split' on the delimiter. Then you would have a list of each word and can probably by pass the regex stuff altogether. Behind the scenes the csv module does a lot of the heavy lifting for you. Have a look at the various methods and see if perhaps you can use some of those rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Would the list work even if I'm looking for consecutive words?

Comment: Well you would test for that by looking at consecutive values in your list. So using csv module with .sniff() you can get the delimiter and create a csv reader object and go through each row in your csv. Each row will be a list. You can then compare consecutive entries on the list, recrd any and then move on to the next row. I would avoid reading one giant string out of your csv as the csv module has already done that, split on new lines, finds the delimiter all for you. Have a look at the output of using csv first because I think that will show you you don't need to parse one enormous string.

Comment: The question evolved from a .txt with one long string to a csv. Open a new question about the csv and we can look at a solution to that.

Comment: The information to check is still in a .txt - the csv is just to determine what to check for in the .txt